# Please help me with the following code

Tags: tables

I am trying to fit the following in one or two tables
Can you please help

```
    \begin{sidewaystable}[]
\centering
\caption{Financial Crises in the sample period}
\label{tab1}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\textbf{Year}   & \textbf{Transmission- Markets}                                                                                                                         & \textbf{Vulnerability-markets}                                                                                                                                       & \textbf{Crisis events}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\
\textbf{1998:1} & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Croatia, Russia, Japan                                                                                                      & Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Austria, USA, Japan, Venezuela                                                                                                          & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. 1997 Asian Financial Crisis (full fledged);  Sourcing from the collapse of Thai baht, resulting in Thailand becoming effectively bankrupt.                                                                   \\ 2. 1998 Russian Financial crisis- Devaluation of the ruble followed by Russian Central Bank defaulting on its debt.\\ 3. 1998 Oil price crash followed.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                \\
\textbf{1998:2} & Malaysia, India, The Phillipines, Singapore, Australia, Chili, Norway                                                                                  & Malaysia, Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Japan, Venezuela                                                                                   &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{1999:1} &                                                                                                                                                        & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Singapore, South Korea, Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Austria, Canada, Russia, Norway, Japan, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Nigeria, Venezuela & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. 1998-1999 Russian Financial Crisis (full fledged).                                                                   \\ 2.  Ecuador financial crisis followed by Brazilian Financial crisis and South American economic crisis. \\ effecting many of the GC countries and spreading through the oil markets into Oil dependent countries.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                              \\
\textbf{1999:2} & USA, Russia, Iraq, Nigeria                                                                                                                             & Malaysia, The Phillipines, South Korea, Germany, France, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Nigeria, Venezuela                                        &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2000:1} & India, South Korea, UK, France, Australia, Croatia, Canada, New Zealand, Israel                                                                        & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Venezuela                                                     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Early 2000s recession effecting Euroopean Union , the USA (commencing).\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession (the lost decade) continued.   \\ 3. The dot com bubble leading to dot comm crash, effecting the USA and Canada mostly.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
\textbf{2000:2} &                                                                                                                                                        & Malaysia, Singapore, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Russia, Saudi Arabia, Venezuela                                                                      &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2001:1} &                                                                                                                                                        & Singapore, South Korea, China, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria,USA, Canada, Russia, New Zealand, Saudi Arabia, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Nigeria                           & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Early 2000s recession continued. \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession (the lost decade) continued.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\
\textbf{2001:2} & Chili,Japan, Iraq, Nigeria                                                                                                                             & Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Canada, Russia, Japan, Venezuela                                                                                                 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2002:1} & India, Croatia,Japan, Sri Lanka, Nigeria                                                                                                               & Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Russia, Iraq                                                                                                                     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. US Stock marker crash in 2002 followed by excessive speculations prevalent in 1997-2000 led from \\ the September 2011 terrorist attack on the USA. \\ 3. Enron bankruptcy , Tyco and Worldcom scandals effected energy stocks around the globe emerging from te USA  \\ 4. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                     \\
\textbf{2002:2} & South Korea, Belgium,USA, Canada                                                                                                                       & India, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Austria, Russia                                                                                                    &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2003:1} & Singapore, South Korea, Germany, UK, France, Croatia, Saudi Arabia                                                                                     & India, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Canada, Russia                                                                                                            & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Global energy crisis- Increasing tensions in Middle East together with rising concerns over oil price \\  speculations followed by a significant fall of US dollar , resulted in oil prices rise abruptly,\\  exceeding three time the price at the beginning.    \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession continued. \\ 4. SARS outbreak : First identified in Guangdong province in China, rapidly took an epidemic form \\  worldwide, slowing down economic interactions with China to many markets.\end{tabular}}      \\
\textbf{2003:2} & The Phillipines, Singapore, RussiaSri Lanka                                                                                                            & India, China, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Iraq, Nigeria                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2004:1} & The Phillipines, Australia, Chili,USA, Canada, New Zealand, Nigeria, Venezuela                                                                         & India, South Korea,Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia,USA, Japan, Israel, Venezuela                                                                                  & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Global energy crisis continued.  \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\
\textbf{2004:2} & Croatia, Japan                                                                                                                                         & Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Venezuela                                                                                                                                 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2005:1} & South Korea, China, Iraq                                                                                                                               & Singapore, Germany, France, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Canada, Russia, Japan, New Zealand, Sri Lanka, Nigeria, Venezuela                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Global energy crisis continued.\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\
\textbf{2005:2} &                                                                                                                                                        & Singapore, South Korea,  Germany, Australia, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Canada, Venezuela                                                            &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2006:1} & South Korea, Russia, Norway,Japan, Saudi Arabia, Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka                                                                               & Singapore, Greece, Portugal,USA, Iraq, Venezuela                                                                                                                     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Global energy crisis continued .\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\\ 3.  GAZA conflict emerges.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
\textbf{2006:2} & India, UK, Canada, Nigeria                                                                                                                             & The Phillipines , South Korea, Greece, Portugal, Japan                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2007:1} &                                                                                                                                                        & India, The Phillipines, South Korea, Greece, Portugal, Canada, Japan, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Sri Lanka, Nigeria                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Global energy crisis continued.   \\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued. \\ 3.  The Global financial crisis emerges.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\
\textbf{2007:2} & Thailand, The Phillipines, India, The  Singapore, South Korea, UK, Australia, Chili, Ireland,USA, Canada, New Zealand, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Venezuela & Thailand, Greece, Portugal, Canada, Russia, Norway, New Zealand                                                                                                      &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2008:1} & China, Chili, Ireland, Belgium, Saudi Arabia                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                                                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Global energy crisis continued. \\ 2. The Global financial crisis continues.\\ 3. 2008 -2011 Icelandic financial crisis leads to credit crisis in UK, hurting the\\  eurozone areas to some extent.\\ 4. Post 2008 Irirsh banking crisis ensues. \\ 5. Russian crisis: the great recession in Russia begins resulting in a full fledged economic crisis in Russia. \\ 6. Spanish financial crisis/ Great Spanish depression begins.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2008:2} & India, Croatia                                                                                                                                         & Singapore, Thailand, Australia                                                                                                                                       &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
\textbf{2009:1} & Croatia, Austria, Canada, Russia, Norway, New Zealand, Israel, Venezuela                                                                               & China, Australia, Ireland, Belgium, Japan, Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka, Venezuela                                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. The post 2008 Irirsh banking crisis left German and French banks exposed , having enormous \\ foreign claims in Greece, Ireland, Portugal, Italy, Spain (Greek crisis countries).\\ 2.  Eurozone crisis/ Greek crisis: In the wake of Great recession in the late 2009 , several Eurozone \\ members (Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Spain, Cyprus) failed to bailout over-indebted banks and repay \\ foreign debt.  \\ 3. 2009-2010 Venezuelan banking crisis occurs. \\ 4.Spanish financial crisis/ Great Spanish depression continues.\end{tabular}} \\
\textbf{2009:2} & India, Singapore,  Germany, UK, Nigeria                                                                                                                & China, Chili, Norway                                                                                                                                                 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Note: Here we arecord only the spikes in trasmissiona and vulnreabilities. Most often, a spike would shift the curves up to a new level and the curves remain upstream until a new spike emerges. Similarly, this can be hold for a curve sliding downhill.}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{tabular}%
    }

\end{sidewaystable}
```

Its a mess.

Comment: Please extend your code to complete small document called MWE (Minimal Working Example). Without knowing the preamble of your document we cant help you. BTW, in columns of `l` types you cant obtain multi line text. use `p{<width>}` column types instead.

Comment: If possible, could you make your question more specific? What is the problem you’re trying to correct, and what is the desired result?

Comment: Don't use resizebox as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. To make the table as wide as the text width, you could use tabularx.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabenum]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin = *, 
                  label = \arabic*.,
                  before = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  after = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \small
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l LLL}
\caption{Financial Crises in the sample period}
\label{tab1}    \\
%
Year 
    & \textbf{Transmission- Markets} 
        & \textbf{Vulnerability-markets}
            & \textbf{Crisis events}    \\  \addlinespace
1998:1 
    & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Croatia, Russia, Japan Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, USA, Japan, Venezuela 
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item 1997 Asian Financial Crisis (full fledged);  Sourcing from the collapse of Thai baht, resulting in Thailand becoming effectively bankrupt.
        \item 1998 Russian Financial crisis- Devaluation of the ruble followed by Russian Central Bank defaulting on its debt.
        \item 1998 Oil price crash followed.
            \end{tabenum}           \\  \addlinespace
1998:2
    & Malaysia, India, The Phillipines, Singapore, Australia, Chili, Norway
        & Malaysia, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Japan, Venezuela
            &                       \\  \addlinespace
1999:1
    &
        & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Singapore, South Korea, Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Austria, Canada, Russia, Norway, Japan, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Nigeria, Venezuela
            &   \begin{tabenum}
            \item 1998-1999 Russian Financial Crisis (full fledged).  
            \item   Ecuador financial crisis followed by Brazilian Financial crisis and South American economic crisis. Effecting many of the GC countries and spreading through the oil markets into Oil dependent countries.
                \end{tabenum}       \\  \addlinespace
1999:2 
    & USA, Russia, Iraq, Nigeria
        & Malaysia, The Phillipines, South Korea, Germany, France, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Nigeria, Venezuela 
            &                       \\  \addlinespace
2000:1
    & India, South Korea, UK, France, Australia, Croatia, Canada, New Zealand, Israel
        & Malaysia, The Phillipines, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Venezuela
        &   \begin{tabenum}
        \item Early 2000s recession effecting Euroopean Union , the USA (commencing).
        \item Japan's 1990s recession (the lost decade) continued.   
        \item The dot com bubble leading to dot comm crash, effecting the USA and Canada mostly.
            \end{tabenum}           \\  \addlinespace
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Formatting the rest of the table i left to you. As you can see, in table body fragment I made the following changes:

- table is not squeezed with `scalebox` (in the name of readers that they will be able to read your table)
- table is in `landscape` environment, since table is huge and not be fit into one page. In this environment you can use `xltabular`, a combination of `tabularx` and `longtable` packages which enable to write multi page long table. It also enable to define repetition of table head on each page (not show in above MWE, but see addendum below)
- all `multirow` cells are replaced with single row cells containing a list adopted for use in table (by help of `enumitem` package)
- for further refinement you should consider my comment below your question.

**Addendum**: 
In case that you like that table to have header on each page, than in above MWE replace lines for table head width:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l LLL}
\caption{Financial Crises in the sample period}
\label{tab1}    \\
    \toprule
Year 
    & \textbf{Transmission- Markets} 
        & \textbf{Vulnerability-markets}
            & \textbf{Crisis events}    \\  \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Financial Crises in the sample period (cont.)}
\label{tab1}    \\
    \toprule
Year
    & \textbf{Transmission- Markets}
        & \textbf{Vulnerability-markets}
            & \textbf{Crisis events}    \\  \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{>{\itshape}r}{Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{@{} >{\bfseries}p{\linewidth} @{}}{%
Note: Here we are cord only the spikes in transmission and vulnerabilities. Most often, a spike would shift the curves up to a new level and the curves remain upstream until a new spike emerges. Similarly, this can be hold for a curve sliding downhill.}
\endlastfoot
```

Using this, the last page with your table will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thank you so much for your kind support. With your code, I am getting the following error " LaTex error: file 'xltabular.sty' not found  main tex line 5

Comment: l.5 \usepackage
               {ragged2e}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

Comment: so its not compiling

Comment: @R.Islam, you need to update your LaTeX installation and add to it missed packages. Since you not gives to us any information about used LaTeX distribution, used engine (`pdLaTeX`; etc), document class etc, is difficult to further help you. Please, edit your question and ad this information.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so fast, Zarko. Really appreciate it. I am working in overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

I came to a solution using ***minipage*** command. Next is your fixed code.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}

 \begin{sidewaystable}[]
 \centering
 \caption{Financial Crises in the sample period}
 \label{tab1}
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%

 \begin{tabular}{llll}
 \textbf{Year}   & \textbf{Transmission- Markets}  & \textbf{Vulnerability-markets}   & \textbf{Crisis events}  \\

 \textbf{1998:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Malaysia,The Phillipines, Croatia, Russia, Japan  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Austria, USA, Japan, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. 1997 Asian Financial Crisis (full fledged);  Sourcing from the collapse of Thai baht, resulting in Thailand becoming effectively bankrupt. \\ 2. 1998 Russian Financial crisis-Devaluation of the ruble followed by Russian Central Bank defaulting on its debt.\\ 3. 1998 Oil price crash followed.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}\\

 \textbf{1998:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Malaysia, India, The Phillipines, Singapore, Australia, Chili, Norway \vspace{0.05in}\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Malaysia, Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Japan, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in}\end{minipage} &  \\ 

 \textbf{1999:1} & & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Malaysia, The Phillipines, Singapore, South Korea, Greece, , Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Austria, Canada, Russia, Norway, Japan, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Nigeria, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. 1998-1999 Russian Financial Crisis (full fledged). \\ 2.  Ecuador financial crisis followed by Brazilian Financial crisis and South American economic crisis.\\ effecting many of the GC countries and spreading through the oil markets into Oil dependent countries.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  \\

\textbf{1999:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}USA, Russia, Iraq, Nigeria \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Malaysia, The Phillipines, South Korea, Germany, France, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Nigeria, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}   &  \\

\textbf{2000:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} India, South Korea, UK, France, Australia, Croatia, Canada, New Zealand, Israel \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Malaysia, The Phillipines, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Croatia, Austria, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. Early 2000s recession effecting Euroopean Union , the USA (commencing).\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession (the lost decade) continued.   \\ 3. The dot com bubble leading to dot comm crash, effecting the USA and Canada mostly.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\ 

\textbf{2000:2} &  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Malaysia, Singapore, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Russia, Saudi Arabia, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \\

\textbf{2001:1} & & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Singapore, South Korea, China, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria,USA, Canada, Russia, New Zealand, Saudi Arabia, Iraq, Sri Lanka, Nigeria  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}   & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Early 2000s recession continued. \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession (the lost decade) continued.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2001:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Chili,Japan, Iraq, Nigeria \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Canada, Russia, Japan, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  &  \\

\textbf{2002:1} &\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} India, Croatia,Japan, Sri Lanka, Nigeria  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Russia, Iraq  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. US Stock marker crash in 2002 followed by excessive speculations prevalent in 1997-2000 led from \\ the September 2011 terrorist attack on the USA. \\ 3. Enron bankruptcy , Tyco and Worldcom scandals effected energy stocks around the globe emerging from te USA  \\ 4. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2002:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}South Korea, Belgium,USA, Canada \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}India, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Austria, Russia  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \\

\textbf{2003:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} Singapore, South Korea, Germany, UK, France, Croatia, Saudi Arabia  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}India, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Austria, Canada, Russia  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Global energy crisis- Increasing tensions in Middle East together with rising concerns over oil price \\  speculations followed by a significant fall of US dollar , resulted in oil prices rise abruptly,\\  exceeding three time the price at the beginning.    \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession continued. \\ 4. SARS outbreak : First identified in Guangdong province in China, rapidly took an epidemic form \\  worldwide, slowing down economic interactions with China to many markets.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}      \\

\textbf{2003:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}The Phillipines, Singapore, RussiaSri Lanka \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}India, China, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Iraq, Nigeria  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \\

\textbf{2004:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}The Phillipines, Australia, Chili,USA, Canada, New Zealand, Nigeria, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}India, South Korea,Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia,USA, Japan, Israel, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. The dot com crash continued.  \\ 2. Global energy crisis continued.  \\ 3. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2004:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Croatia, Japan\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \\

\textbf{2005:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}South Korea, China, Iraq \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Singapore, Germany, France, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Belgium, Canada, Russia, Japan, New Zealand, Sri Lanka, Nigeria, Venezuela   \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. Global energy crisis continued.\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2005:2} &  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Singapore, South Korea,  Germany, Australia, Chili, Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Croatia, Canada, Venezuela   \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \\

\textbf{2006:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} South Korea, Russia, Norway,Japan, Saudi Arabia, Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Singapore, Greece, Portugal,USA, Iraq, Venezuela  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. Global energy crisis continued .\\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued.\\ 3.  GAZA conflict emerges.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2006:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} India, UK, Canada, Nigeria  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}The Phillipines , South Korea, Greece, Portugal, Japan   \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} &  \\

\textbf{2007:1} & & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}India, The Phillipines, South Korea, Greece, Portugal, Canada, Japan, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Sri Lanka, Nigeria  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. Global energy crisis continued.   \\ 2. Japan's 1990s recession continued. \\ 3.  The Global financial crisis emerges.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2007:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Thailand, The Phillipines, India, The Singapore, South Korea, UK, Australia, Chili, Ireland,USA, Canada, New Zealand, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Thailand, Greece, Portugal, Canada, Russia, Norway, New Zealand \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \\

\textbf{2008:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}China, Chili, Ireland, Belgium, Saudi Arabia \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} &  &\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. Global energy crisis continued. \\ 2. The Global financial crisis continues.\\ 3. 2008 -2011 Icelandic financial crisis leads to credit crisis in UK, hurting the\\  eurozone areas to some extent.\\ 4. Post 2008 Irirsh banking crisis ensues. \\ 5. Russian crisis: the great recession in Russia begins resulting in a full fledged economic crisis in Russia. \\ 6. Spanish financial crisis/ Great Spanish depression begins.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  \\

\textbf{2008:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} India, Croatia  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}Singapore, Thailand, Australia  \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \\

\textbf{2009:1} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} Croatia, Austria, Canada, Russia, Norway, New Zealand, Israel, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}China, Australia, Ireland, Belgium, Japan, Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka, Venezuela \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} 1. The post 2008 Irirsh banking crisis left German and French banks exposed , having enormous \\ foreign claims in Greece, Ireland, Portugal, Italy, Spain (Greek crisis countries).\\ 2.  Eurozone crisis/ Greek crisis: In the wake of Great recession in the late 2009 , several Eurozone \\ members (Greece, Portugal, Ireland, Spain, Cyprus) failed to bailout over-indebted banks and repay \\ foreign debt.  \\ 3. 2009-2010 Venezuelan banking crisis occurs. \\ 4.Spanish financial crisis/ Great Spanish depression continues.\vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} \\

\textbf{2009:2} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in} India, Singapore,  Germany, UK, Nigeria \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}China, Chili, Norway \vspace{0.05in} \end{minipage}   & \\

\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Note: Here we arecord only the spikes in trasmissiona and vulnreabilities. Most often, a spike would shift the curves up to a new level and the curves remain upstream until a new spike emerges. Similarly, this can be hold for a curve sliding downhill.}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

Comment: See/consider comment of  @leandriis below your question!